# Date formatter in Objective-C returns null

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I don't understand why my `dateFormatter` returns null. The code is very simple, but I don't see any mistakes here. I have also tried to use `setDateFormat`, but without any result. What is the problem with the code?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
mikey.hireDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Aug 02, 2010"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your date formatter's locale to `EN_US_POSIX`. That way, the device's region will not alter the formatter.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] 
                 initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped. So, xcode is using my device's current location to change the format of the date or what? Could you explain in more detail why we should initialize the date formatter with the locale, please?

Comment: Right. The date formatter is always using the actual device's locale by default. For example, if a user uses their phone in Chinese, "Aug" will be an undefined short month because it's in English.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my machine; with that said, if you want to parse date strings from user input, NSDataDetector is generally a better way to go than NSDateFormatter.